# Message received is displayed twice in ReactJs and useEffect. Tell me what I am doing wrong

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

```
    if (currentMessage !== "") {
      const messageData = {
        room: room,
        author: username,
        message: currentMessage,
        time:
          new Date(Date.now()).getHours() +
          ":" +
          new Date(Date.now()).getMinutes(),
      };

      await socket.emit("send_message", messageData);
      setMessageList((list) => [...list, messageData]);
      setCurrentMessage("");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
      setMessageList((list) => [...list, data]);
    });
  }, [socket]);
```

In the output, I am receiving one message twice in the receiver side.
I have figured this has to be related to useEffect Hook.
Please help.

Comment: Have you checked whether this is a result of having [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having Strict Mode enabled in React
that was causing the problem.
Now its working fine.